# Parameterized SQL query in Entity framework to avoid SQL Injection

Tags: entity-framework, sql-injection, sqlcommand

I have been using below code to execute my SQL Query, which looks something like this

```
SELECT abc.... FROM .... (many joins).. WHERE userid =" + userId + " AND UserState = " +userState ...; (Other parameters)
```

Below is how I am running the query and returning datatable

```
using (var context = new DbContext())
            {
                DataTable dt= new DataTable();
                var conn = context.Database.Connection;
                var connectionState = conn.State;
                try
                {
                    if (connectionState != ConnectionState.Open)
                        conn.Open();

                    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                    {

                        cmd.CommandText = buildveryLongQuery(userId,userState);

                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            if (reader.HasRows)
                                dt.Load(reader);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

above method is working fine but it provides SQL injection. how can I parametrized it?

I tried below method:

Changed query to use @userId

```
IDbDataParameter personParam = cmd.CreateParameter();
personParam.DbType = DbType.Int32;
personParam.ParameterName = "@userId";
personParam.Value = userId;
```

but I am getting below error

> Must declare the scalar variable \"@userId\

Comment: The parameter markers must be integrated into the query text returned from `buildveryLongQuery(userId,userState);`.

Comment: why are you using dbcontext solely to use its connection, and not use its SqlQuery<> function?

Comment: Which entity framework are you using?  Most have a mechanism to create view objects which allow for binds / parameterized queries.